# websocket error: can't connect socket.io to react-native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I am using [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-with-bundlers/) Version: ^4.5.1 in a chat application, but I am facing this error:

```
websocket error
```

my code:

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
import {server} from 'store/config';

export const connectSocket = (token: string, eventId: string) => {
  const socket = io(server.stageSocketUrl, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  });

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');
    socket.emit('join', {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      eventId,
    });
  });

  socket.on('connect_error', err => {
    console.log(err, 'connect error');
  });
  return {socket};
};
```

when I use `"socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"` it connects to server successfully, so any clue how can I use version ^4.5.1 and make websocket connect to the server?